# What should I use to deploy a python based image analysis program for an end-user on a server

Tags: python, django, user-interface, data-visualization, web-frameworks

I have written an SEM (Scanning electron image)-image analysis program in Python which is capable of calculating all the microstructural properties in an SEM image e.g. Identification of different areas in the image 2) calculate the area of specific regions in microns, diameters, circularity, etc. The final results are in the form of a graph(area in microns vs cumulative frequency vs percentage contribution) plotted with the help of Matplotlibrary in Python. I want to give this program on a server where anyone can use it through an interface without looking at the code. I am confused that what should I use to do so? Will Django be a good choice for this? But I suspect Django cannot perform all the tasks (Not sure). I have also read about Jenkins servers. Please guide me which approach should I use to deploy this image analysis program for any user on a server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cool stuff!

If you want to make a server where other user can interact with your program using a user interface then yes Django (or even better Flask) will work.

A very basic structure for your program is to have one endpoint which will render a simple html home page with a form input for uploading a file. Once the file is uploaded, the form is shipped to your backend which will accept the file and give it as an input to your python function for SEM file analysis. The function could then generate a figure which the user will be able to download. That would however require setting up a database (which is usually simple with Django). So yes you can go either with Django or Flask and everything should fall into place.

However, be careful with research project aimed towards people that do not want to deal with scripting or code. I've made a few research project like this for brain imaging data (with a GUI and all) and all of these project ended up being a huge time sink. There will be updates to the analysis to do, bugs on the user interface to fix and cryptic compatibility issues. I've come to the realization that it is much better to have the minimal amount of user interface for a project like this and spend more time documenting how to make the code run on the command line using a well crafted README.md. This allows you to focus on what has a lot of value for your research and also helps other people learn valuable skills.

Anyway, that last paragraph was just my opinion! If you feel like setting up a full-blown website for this project go for it!